# Reason for: Trying to get property of non-object in php

Tags: php

```
    if(isset($_POST['uname'])) 
    {       
        $query = "SELECT * FROM user_info";
        $res = $mysqli->query($query);
        $num = $res->num_rows;
        $i = 0;     
        $cpwd = $_POST["pswd"];
        $hpwd = SHA1($cpwd);
        $tmp = $_POST["uname"]; 
        while($i < $num)
        {
            $row = $res->fetch_object();
            $name = $row->Username;
            $pwd = $row->Password;  
            if($name == $tmp)
            {       
                   //check if user is blocked
            }
            //hashed pwd
            if($pwd == $hpwd)
            {   
                //success
                exit();
            }   
            //request for pwd change
        else if($pwd == $cpwd)
            {
            //change
                exit();
            }
            else if($pwd != $hpwd)
            {

                //incorrect pwd
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
    if($i == $num)
    {
        //new user
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you incrementing `$i` somewhere?

Comment: I wonder if anyone will notice a **real** bug in that code

Comment: Is "Trying to get property of non-object in php" the PHP error you are getting? (= yes), then why don't you just give us also the line where you are getting this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you're somehow looping past the end of the array and `$row` is actually `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

So `$res->fetch_object()` did not return an object. Take a look at the documentation of this function. What does it return when it finds nothing?

Comment: @Kuttu: do you mean `var_dump($row)` prints an error message? I guess it would rather return `false` or something.

Comment: I'm not asking what you're getting without it, but with it. But lonesomeday seems to know this. Now you should try to understand why you're getting nothing. Is your database empty?

Comment: Nope.. not at ol... for the first request it returns the error... and not for the subsequent requests...

Comment: @Kuttu: For the *first* query?!? This is quite strange. I guess you should show us more of your code (until this end of the while)

Comment: @Kuttu: you seem to be searching for a given user in php. Why not do it directly in SQL? I know he was rude, but Col. Shrapnel has given an example of a fairly better piece of code to do this job. Consider using it.

Answer (score 1):

some times num_rows return 1, even if no rows effected. Try to use

```
while($row = $res->fetch_object())
```

or
you forget to increment $i :)

Answer (score 1):

get rid of that junk and make it like this

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE Username = ? AND Password = ?";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["uname"], SHA1($_POST["pswd"]));
$stmt->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error());
if (!$mysqli->affected_rows) {
  //no such user
}
```

I've never used mysqli myself, so, there may be typos.
But I hope you'll be able to get the idea.